# full recovery with huge log file

Tags: sql, sql-server, system

In a sql server database with a full model backup with tran logs backed up every 15 minutes, but ,still, the log file is huge.
I suspect I should act on the target recovery time parameter (60 sec actually) perhaps ..

[image: logspace]
[image: logspace2]
[[image: logspace_vlfstatus[3]]
recently I found a method to shrink it :

shrink the DB after doing the following task :

/*
Perform a full backup of your database.

Change the backup method of your database to "Simple"

Open a query window and enter "checkpoint" and execute

Perform another backup of the database

Perform a final full backup of the database.
*/

Comment: Is the log file itself huge but hardly used - EXEC SQLPERF(LogSpace) - the log itself will remain at a certain size even immediately after a log backup but could have a lot of empty space there. You could try and shrink the log (if there's free space) but just be aware, it may grow again until next Log Backup and you're back to square one. Take care with ANY shrinks (and don't even think about Auto Shrink!)

Comment: Here are the results :                                                                                   
Log Size (MB)
11799,99
Log Space Used (%)
29,30282
Status
0

Comment: I've tried a lot of BCC SHRINKFILE (databasename, 5000) WITH NO_INFOMSGS and similar commands but no result

Comment: define "no result" - did it appear to hang for a long period of time? That can be quite normal if the log is in use often - If so, bump up the number to 10000 or higher and do it in stages or do it at a quiet period. That said, in the end, the log needed to be that big at some point, it's probably going to get there again at some point in the future.

Comment: "no result"  == no significant change in the log file's dimensions , tks I will try in quiet periods (night)

Comment: No that was more for if it was processing for a long time. If it did nothing and the log file hasn't shrunk at all, then I suggest posting pictures of the SQLPERF command above, along with query from @andrey nikolov below and, sorry to say, check the log backup is actually backing the log up. It should be shrinkable at some point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction log backup will not shrink the files. If they grew, after backup the space will be marked as available and reused, but the file size will not be reduced. However, if you tried to shrink it and it didn't, then probably the log is still in use. Is anything else that uses the transaction log, which prevents if from truncating? Check the result of this command:

```
SELECT log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases where name = N'<database_name>';
```

It it shows anything other than NOTHING or LOG_BACKUP, you can't shrink it, because something else is using it.

Comment: sometimes LOG_BACKUP, but most of times NOTHING

Comment: LOG_BACKUP is when there are logged operations not backed up, NOTHING is right after log backup completes. These are normal. Did you ever tried to shrink your log?

Comment: During nothing state, I've tried a lot of DBCC SHRINKFILE (databasename, 5000) WITH NO_INFOMSGS and similar commands but no result, the log file is 11.800 MB

Comment: Using database name doesn't looks correct to me. It should be the log file's logical file name. Usually it is "databasename_log". Try to execute DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'MyDatabase_Log' , 5000) instead.Or use the UI in SSMS.

Comment: yes, of course, sorry I wrote the database log in query, I mismatched the obfuscation

Comment: And your log size isn't reduced after that? This is strange! What is the result of this query? SELECT total_log_size_in_bytes, used_log_space_in_bytes FROM sys.dm_db_log_space_usage;

Comment: nosignificant reduction total_log_size_in_bytes
9621725184
used_log_space_in_bytes
1237132288

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183141/discussion-between-andrey-nikolov-and-gabriele-donufrio).